# Sum of Binomial distribution

Tags: probability, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem, binomial-distribution

I am struggling to show the following -

$$\sum_{N_{H}=0}^{N} \frac{N!}{N_{H}!(N-N_{H}!)}f_{H}(1-f_{H})^{N-N_{H}} = (f_{H}+(1-f_{H}))^N$$

I would like to prove it without doing induction. I'm sure it's quite simple but I can't seem to figure it out!

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you have a mistake. $(f_{H}+(1-f_{H}))^N = 1^N = 1$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\sum_{N_{H} = 0}^{N}{N! \over N_{H}!\pars{N - N_{H}!}}
\,f_{H}\pars{1 - f_{H}}^{N - N_{H}} & =
f_{H}\sum_{N_{H} = 0}^{N}{N \choose N_{H}}\,\pars{1 - f_{H}}^{N_{H}} =
f_{H}\bracks{1 + \pars{1 - f_{H}}}^{N}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\ds{f_{H}\pars{2 - f_{H}}^{N}}}
\end{align}